Can't get data from qml
I need to get data for further use in c++, but it gives me errors:

QObject::connect(QQuickWindow, QDeclarativeGeoMap): invalid nullptr parameter


QObject::connect(QQuickWindow, QDeclarativeGeoMap): invalid nullptr parameter


QGeoTileProviderOsm: Tileserver disabled at  QUrl("http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.8/satellite")


QGeoTileFetcherOsm: all providers resolved


QGeoTileProviderOsm: Tileserver disabled at  QUrl("http://maps-redirect.qt.io/osm/5.8/satellite")


QGeoTileFetcherOsm: all providers resolved

QT version 5.15.2
Here's my part of QML:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Rectangle {
    id: telecom
    width: 800
    height: 600

    signal setRect(double x, double y, double width, double height)

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(55.7558, 37.6173)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MouseArea {
            id: mapMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                mapMouseArea.active = true
            }
            onReleased: {
                mapMouseArea.active = false
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 0
        height: 0
        color: "blue"
        opacity: 0.5
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 2
        visible: false

        x: 100
        y: 100
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            rect.x = mouseArea.mouseX
            rect.y = mouseArea.mouseY
            rect.width = 0
            rect.height = 0
            rect.visible = true
        }

        onReleased: {
            rect.width = Math.abs(mouseArea.mouseX - rect.x)
            rect.height = Math.abs(mouseArea.mouseY - rect.y)
            setRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
        }
...

main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    RectangleHandler rectangleHandler;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rectangleHandler", &rectangleHandler);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/places_map.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &a, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
                         if (!obj && url == objUrl) {
                             qCritical() << "Error 1";
                             QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
                         }
                     }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        qCritical() << "Error 2";
        return -1;
    }

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}


This question is similar to: QObject::connect(QQuickWindow, QDeclarativeGeoMap): invalid nullptr parameter. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the following line in main.cpp, you passed <&a> as an argument for the function. But you did not declare variable <a> before. I think the nullptr error caused by this fault.
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &a, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl)


There is a QApplication a defined in line 3.
